# How to delete parent of child being monitored by ReadDirectoryChangesW

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, readdirectorychangesw, change-notification

Monitoring a folder with ReadDirectoryChangesW causes its parent to be locked and can't be deleted.

There is a post about this here:

[FindFirstChangeNotification locks parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962294/findfirstchangenotification-locks-parent-folder/51902461?noredirect=1#comment90756081_51902461)

but the only solution mentioned in it is that we should always listen at the top level.

Has anyone found out a better way to do this instead of watching at the top level?

Sometimes this can go all the way to watching the Drive and that can't take a lot of process time on a machine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

folder can be deleted only in case it empty, otherwise we got error `STATUS_DIRECTORY_NOT_EMPTY` - *Indicates that the directory trying to be deleted is not empty.*

from another side - if you have opening handle for file - it can not be deleted until you not close it handle (*something here changed begin from win10 rs1*)

so if you monitor some child sub-folder with `ReadDirectoryChangesW` you have opened handle to it, and parent can not (*before WIN10_RS1*) be deleted until you not close this handle.

in general process look like - when somebody try delete folder - it must enumerate all files(sub-folders) inside it and delete it first. when delete operation will be apply on folder for which `ReadDirectoryChangesW` called - the io request will be completed with status `STATUS_DELETE_PENDING` - *A non close operation has been requested of a file object with a delete pending.* (it converted to win32 error code `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` - *Access is denied.*). when you got this error from `ReadDirectoryChangesW` you must close your directory handle used in this call. then is raise - who is first - you close directory handle or another code try delete parent folder...

---

begin from win10 rs1 possible delete parent, even if somebody hold open handle to it child file(folder) by calling [`NtSetInformationFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with [`FileDispositionInformationEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information_ex) or [`SetFileInformationByHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileinformationbyhandle) with [`FileDispositionInfoEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information_ex).

the magic here in new flag `FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS` (*Specifies the system should perform a POSIX-style delete*)

> Normally a file marked for deletion is not actually deleted until all
>   open handles for the file have been closed and the link count for the
>   file is zero. When marking a file for deletion using
>   `FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS`, the link gets removed from the
>   visible namespace as soon as the POSIX delete handle has been closed,
>   but the file’s data streams remain accessible by other existing
>   handles until the last handle has been closed.

so when we use this - file itself of course will be not deleted, until caller of `ReadDirectoryChangesW` not close self handle, but file will be removed from the parent folder. as result parent folder can became empty, after which we can delete it.

note that `DeleteFileW` and `RemoveDirectoryW` here will be not work here, because they used old information class [FileDispositionInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntsetinformationfile) with [`FILE_DISPOSITION_INFORMATION`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information)

```
ULONG DeletePosix(PCWSTR lpFileName)
{
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(lpFileName, DELETE, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS|FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT, 0);

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }

    static FILE_DISPOSITION_INFO_EX fdi = { FILE_DISPOSITION_DELETE| FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS };

    ULONG dwError = SetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, FileDispositionInfoEx, &fdi, sizeof(fdi)) 
        ? NOERROR : GetLastError();

    // win10 rs1: file removed from parent folder here
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    return dwError;
}
```

and of course child must be open with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` in other calls, otherwise we simply can not open it with `DELETE` access later

Comment: Note that `FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS ` can fail (e.g. if file system is not NTFS), so you should try a regular delete in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to specify the right attributes to `CreateFile()` when you obtain the directory handle. Try this:

```
HANDLE hDir = ::CreateFile(
    strDirectoryName,
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE, 
    NULL, // security descriptor
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
    NULL);
```

It is important to specify `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` as well for the share mode.