# ReadDirectoryChangesExW prevents folder rename above target directory

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

## Background

I am using the ReadDirectoryChangesExW API to monitor for file changes on a windows file system. Currently I can rename folders and files **underneath** the target directory and I get all the events as expected. I can process renames and deletes and moves just fine.

Here is how I am calling the ReadDirectoryChanges and setting up the handles ahead of time for use within the call

**Setup Code:**

```
mTargetDirHandle = CreateFile(targetRootDir.c_str(), FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
                   NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, NULL);
mAsyncCallInfo.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL);
DWORD mNotifyFilterBitmask = FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME |
                                 FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE | FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_CREATION |
                                 FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE;
```

**ReadDirectoryChangesExW Code:**

```
ReadDirectoryChangesExW(mTargetDirHandle, buffer, FS_CHANGE_BUFFER_SIZE,TRUE,
                        mNotifyFilterBitmask, NULL, &mAsyncCallInfo,
                        NULL, ReadDirectoryNotifyExtendedInformation);
```

## Problem

The problem I am having is dealing with the case where I want to allow **folder renames** above the target directory. I want to give my users this flexibility and just resolve the absolute file paths on my own within my application.

**Example Filesystem**

```
C:/
├─ dev/
│  ├─ project/
│  │  ├─ target_dir/
│  │  ├─ other_folder/
│  ├─ other_project/
```

Say the user wants to rename dev/ to dev1/. I will get a *"the action cannot be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program"* error.

I have used process explorer to verify that my application that is monitoring for file changes indeed has a handle open to C:/dev/project/target_dir. Im assuming this is the issue.

## Things I have Tried

I have tried opening a handle to C:/ and monitoring for directory renames within C:/dev/project/target_dir with a separate monitor. This works for renaming target_dir and being able to maintain my applications monitoring. However, this still fails when renaming dev or project because the shared handle opened on target_dir locks those folders down.

I have also tried looking at how others have done file monitoring. Solutions like Git's FsMonitor and facebook/Meta's Watchman all are doing their ReadDirectoryChangesExW calls pretty much exactly how I am doing it. I imagine they must be running into the same limitations, but I have not tested that yet.

**Final Thoughts**

To be clear, I can rename other_project or other_folder, I just cant rename folders in the critical path of target_dir (dev and project).

Is this just a limitation of the ReadDirectoryChangesExW API? Is it possible to open a handle in windows that can be used with readdirchanges that would allow folder renames above the target directory?

I know theoretically, I could monitor C:/ and filter down for directories I care about, but this is not sustainable when a windows machine is going through system updates, etc. Monitoring for folder renames only at C:/ is fine, but I dont think monitoring for all changes is possible long-term at C:/.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27962294/103167 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/65694700/103167

Comment: Actually ,if you think about it ,it's only logical. you cannot rename/move a directory that has a file or subdirectory open ,period !

Comment: @engf-010 Yeah I figured this might be a thing. I was hoping that if we the user (me) took responsibility for it, we could ask the API to let things be renamed and we would hook into those events and deal with it.

Comment: @BenVoigt I appreciate the related questions. I think I even stumbled upon one of these while doing initial research. Unfortunately, both look like they confirm my suspicion that there is no way to work around my file HANDLE locking down parent directories.